# 'True' transparent form background colour vb.net

Tags: vb.net, forms, winforms, transparency, alpha-transparency

So, I have been looking around to find out how to make the form background transparent in a windows forms application. I have found a few things that work to an extent however they are not working the way I want.

The way I am trying to use it is by setting the form transparency and then drawing the graphics onto the form myself.

One way I tried is by setting the forms transparency key to white, and then making the forms background colour the same. To test this, I am using this code to make a simple semi-transparent red box:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim test As New Bitmap(100, 100)
    Dim testGraphic = Graphics.FromImage(test)

    Dim newColor As Color = Color.FromArgb(150, 150, 0, 0)

    testGraphic.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(newColor), 0, 0, 50, 50)
    testGraphic.Dispose()

    Me.CreateGraphics.DrawImage(test, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

When the button is clicked, the box is created and drawn to the form. However, as you can see here, the white background from the form mixes with the semi-transparent red colour of the box and you are not able to see through it.

[image: Transparent Windows Form]
]

I'm having some problems trying to find a solution to this as I'm not too sure how to word it, so if anyone could help me out that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, it's not possible to do true transparency with WinForms. WPF provides full support.

Comment: Google "layered windows"